# Where to find LM-Hashes

Tags: hash, protocols, sam

Are there any other places besides the SAM file?

Are LM-Hashes used in any protocols, so they can be found by scanning the network traffic?

Answer (score 0):

If program using lm hashes in network communication without encryption. Yes, you can simple found it by sniffing the network traffic.

Comment: Protocol is a variable depends on application. You must consider applications one by one by protocol.

Answer (score 0):

what you want
if Password in SAM file
then I will recommend to use Backtrack .you can easily find the Hash
using backtrack (as it have many tools) just u have to copy the SAM file and System File from. (windows/System32/config/) to Backtrack And Enjoy (you can find many  tutorials easily on google)

Comment: Welcome on SO. A good answer would include the links. May be you can improve your answer a little bit.